# fixed background in responsive design HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am converting a static page to responsive and the page has a fixed background image. The only way I can think of to deal with this is to re-make the image so it can be scaled as the screen increases and decreases. Any ideas, thoughts?

current css

```
body{
margin:0; 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size:12px;
color:#f1f1f1; 
background: #00171d url(../images/splash-images/body-bg.jpg) repeat-x fixed;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? A snippet? A `fiddle`? What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: CSS 'background-size' property might be useful depending on what you need.

Comment: This might help you  - 

background: url(images/bg.png) center top no-repeat;

-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;

Answer (score 1):

Instead of re-editing the image where you would need to make multiple images for different screen sizes.
Try this

Fixed div with 100 percent width and height
and the image file inside with a 100 percent width and height as well
like so:

```
<style>
   #fixed_div { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:1; }
   #fixed_div img { width:100%; height:100%; }
</style>

<div id="fixed_div">
   <img src="img">
</div>
```

The code will fluidly re-size the image when the browser is re-sized.

use css's **min-width, max-width, min-height and max-height** to set boundaries to the image.
also use z-index to correctly stack you divs.